# Passing a value in a where: block in Spock test

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

Is it possible to pass a value in where block like this.

I have tried this. But it fails and gives MissingPropertyException.

And I want the name1 and name2 to be inside the method.

```
def "length of names #name"()  {    
        def name1 = "Spock"
        def name2 = "Java"

        expect:
            name.size() == length

        where:
            name        || length
            name1       || 5
            name2       || 2
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
def "test length of names"()  {
    expect:
        name.size() == length   
    where:
    [name,length]<<getTestData()

}

def getTestData(){
        [["Ram"  ,3 ] ,["Test" ,4] ]
    }
```

Hope that helps!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Test data belongs in the where block, not hard coded in the test (feature) method.

One rough way to see this is to think of the test body (excluding the where block) as a method with some number of parameters -- 2 in your case, name and length. And then realize that the where clause just provides data values to the test runner to use when invoking your test method.

Spock uses Groovy magic to transform

```
def "test length of names"()  {
    expect:
        name.size() == length   
    where:
        name     | length
        "Spock"  | 5
        "Java"   | 4
}
```

into something roughly like

```
def test_length_of_names(name, length)  { // note the arguments
    assert name.size() == length
}
```

and then tells the test runner to call the test once for each row in the where clause

```
test_length_of_names("Spock", 5)
test_length_of_names("Java", 4)
```

This approach

- provides a nice separation of concerns between test logic and test data
- allows relatively generic tests to be reused for a wide range of inputs and edge cases
- avoids duplication in test code
- supports a test design style that deserves the name data-driven testing.

This explanation leaves out a few details, such as creating an instance of the spec for each test, updating the name of each test invocation and calling the various setup and cleanup methods.

See [the Spock documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs) for more details.

Comment: Yes the "_where_" data is outside the feature test but yet the way Spock's lexical layout functions it _appears_ inside the feature. Btw, that "Spock documentation" link is broken.  Concerning the "*where clause*" -- I'd like a mechanism to reuse data.  (Say) that `Where` were an interface that allowed the `private Where getTestData(){...}` to return a where table from Anuj's example.  And of course I'd prefer to have the tidy table syntax.  Thanks for the very clear explanation.

Comment: The documentation link is fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.