# load where clause from a file in groovy

Tags: groovy

This question is an extension of this question [Passing a value in a where: block in Spock test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015236/passing-a-value-in-a-where-block-in-spock-test/19015605) .

```
def "test length of names"()  {
    expect:
        name.size() == length   
    where:
    [name,length]<<getTestData()

}

def getTestData(){
   new File('./path/toFile/nameInfo.txt').text
}
```

I am trying to load the testData from a file.But this does not work. What am I missing here?

Comment: you have to parse file depending on its format and return an array of [name,length] pairs (according to your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getData` method is returning a `String`.

You cannot use that as test data using 2 columns `name` and `length` as you are trying to because Groovy doesn't know how to turn a `String` into those variables (or a List with 2 elements for that matter).

If you want your Spock test to have examples coming from a File, you need to parse the File first into a format that Spock can work with.

Here's an example that should help you get started, first without a File:

```
def "test length of names"()  {
    def (name, length) = example
    expect:
        name.size() == length   
    where:
    example << getTestData()

}

List getTestData(){
   [
     ['foo', 3],
     ['a', 1],
   ]
}
```

This works because Groovy lets you "destructure" a List (Spock also does, see edit below) with `def (a1, a2...) = list`, and you can probably generate a List like this from your file...

Say your File is in this format:

```
foo 3
b 1
```

Parsing it into a List of 2-item Lists is really easy:

```
List getTestData() {
  def lines = new File('./path/toFile/nameInfo.txt').readLines()
  return lines.collect { it.split(' ').toList() }
}
```

Putting everything together, your test should work now.

**EDIT**

Spock actually does support "destructuring" as well! TIL here's how to improve the above example using Spock instead of Groovy destructuring:

```
def "test length of names #name #length"()  {
    expect:
    name.size() == length
    where:
    [name, length] << getTestData()
}
```

Comment: excellent I had figured it out but appreciate your answer and time. I have selected your answer as the solution